# Windows phone database. How to erase table fast?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

What can i use instead of

```
db.Schedules.DeleteAllOnSubmit(db.Schedules);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

For table with 1M records it takes ages.

Can i execute Stored Procedure or any custom SQL somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Erik, the question is how to erase table, not database.

Comment: Isolate the table in a single Database file (DataContext), and erase the database with db.DeleteDatabase as required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures are not supported on the phone.

What you are trying will take a long time because you have a lot of records to delete.
There are a couple of things you could try instead:
- delete the file the table is in directly
- split (shard) the data across multiple tables so that you don't have to delete so many records at the same time.